# Apply XOR operator in a lambda function

Tags: php, function, xor

My issue is a bit haywire, I must admit before I carry on. So please do not ask me why I need this. Here goes:

Suppose I have an anonymous function of this sort:

```
$_ = function(){return true;};
```

What I aim to achieve is to alter the syntax using the XOR operator as follows:

```
$_ = ("&"^"@").('*'^'_').("."^"@").('<'^'_').("+"^"_").("@"^")").("/"^"@").("."^"@").(){return true;};
```

This is met as invalid syntax by PHP. Same goes if I try to append the value of the string '**function**' to a variable and then use it as shown below:

```
$__ = ("&"^"@").('*'^'_').("."^"@").('<'^'_').("+"^"_").("@"^")").("/"^"@").("."^"@")
```

$_ = $__(){return true;}

Therefore, my question is how could I possibly approach this case and use a XORed value of the keyword '**function**'. *I know it is possible but fail to perceive how it's being realised.*

> Thank you in advance for any solutions/guidelines/answers!

Comment: You can't directly use keywords from variables. You'd have to use `eval` or create a function from a string and execute it or something.

Comment: Indeed but how would I do this? I cannot eval the XOR value.

Comment: You'd have to `eval` the entire thing; you simply *can't* use a keyword from a string unless you run the parser over again.

Comment: `eval('$_ = ' . ('&'.'@')./* ... */ . '(){return true;};');`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you, PHP doesn't allow you to use a calculated value as a keyword. To over-simplify, PHP has three stages: lexing, parsing, and execution. Keywords are used during the parsing process, and your XORs are calculated during execution. To use your calculated value as a keyword, you'd have to redo the parsing process.

Fortunately for you, in PHP, that's possible using `eval`, although it has to be a whole new piece of code rather than, say, a single `function` token. `eval` needs a whole chunk of code, so you'll need to assemble the whole thing into a string:

```
$myKeyword = 'function';  // XORs don't matter; the problem is it's calculated
$code = '$myResult = ' . $myKeyword . '() { return true; };';
```

Then you can pass that to `eval`:

```
eval($code);  // you could, of course, bypass the intermediate $code variable
```

Your function is now in `$myResult`:

```
$myResult();  // => true
```

Of course, you'd never want to use this in code you intend to be readable, but I'm almost certain you're just trying to obfuscate your code, in which case readability is intended to be poor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that fully satisfies my question! Good information and well spoken. Thanks :)